One-product free sequences for $A_n$
I am working on computing the Davenport constant $D(G)$ for $S_n$ and $A_n$, i.e., the minimal number $d$ such that every sequence (multiset) of $d$ elements contains some subsequence giving identity as a product, in some order. The small Davenport constant $d(G)$ is the maximal length of a one-free sequence, i.e., $d(G)+1=D(G)$.
In particular, for $A_n$ I want to get a lower bound by computing a general family of one-product free sequences for each $n$. For $A_3$ we know $d(A_3)=2$ with maximal one-product free sequence {(123),(123)}. For $A_4$, we have $d(A_4)=4$ with maximal one product free sequence {(123), (123), (134), (134)} and for $A_5$ we know $d(A_5)=8$ with maximal one-product free {(12345) x 4, (12453) x4}. No other value is known. Moreover, in these three cases $d(A_n)=2^{n-2}$, is this coincidence or could be proved to be some lower/upper bound?
I am looking for patterns to get maximal one-product free sequences for $A_n$ in general and $n=6$ and $n=7$ in particular. One of them, looking at the examples, could be for $n$ odd getting $n-1$ copies of some set of $n$-cycles. For $n$ even, one possible idea could be taking maximal sequence of $A_{n-1}$ and taking another copy conjugating all elements by some $g$ not fixing $n$.
Does anyone come up with some idea to get one-free sequences in $A_n$? Apart from the obvious one of taking $m-1$ times an element of order $m$. Similarly, any idea for getting upper bounds for $D(A_n)$ are also very welcome and helpful ;)
Thank you very much in advance!

Minor point: the statements of known values of $D$ look to actually be known values of $d$. More usefully, the Sage code I posted earlier elsewhere can't find a set of three elements of $A_6$ which give a one-product-free multiset of 12 elements. The best is 11 with e.g. $(1,5,4,3,2)^3, (1,6,5,2,3)^4, (1,3,6,2,4)^4$. That rather spoils the idea of finding four $5$-cycles to give a multiset $c_1^4, c_2^4, c_3^4, c_4^4$.

@PeterTaylor Thanks a lot once again! I am definitely going to use your Sage code from now on since it is very useful for the calculations I need!  I really appreciate your help ;)

@PeterTaylor If I understood well, the code runs thrugh all possible subsequence products, with all possible ordering right? Because that is so important point, for a fixed subsequence taking the different orders for the product into account!

Yes, that's the bottleneck. I can't think of a way to represent the partial products in such a way that you can add one element and generate all of the partial products with it in arbitrary positions, so it recalculates a lot.

@PeterTaylor Yes, I agree! I asked you this since there is some contradiction I do not understand why it fails, maybe you could help me or my computer does not compute it correctly. As you previously mentioned in one comment above there is some one-free sequence of length 11 in $A_6$ with three distict elements, thus adding any odd permutation in $S_6$ it should be one-free sequence of length 12 in $S_6$ with 4 distinct elements. However, in the Sage code it seems not to exist such a sequence, when I look for it. Do you know why could that be?

I'm not sure how you're setting up the check. Can you post your code somewhere?

@PeterTaylor I am literally taking the Sage code you posted in the answer of the other question for $D(S_5)$, and changing the last parameters   instead of oneFreeProduct(S5, 10, 3) now I write oneFreeProduct(S6, 12. 4). I just change that line.

It takes a while, but it gives me {(1,6,5,4,3,2): 1, (2,6,5,4,3): 3, (1,4,6,2,5): 4, (1,6,3,5,2): 4}

@PeterTaylor Okay, thanks a lot! It seems I have to wait bit more then! The point is that the symbol of "loading" disappears after some time, which makes me think the computation is over. It seems it is not, or my computer does not wanna work ;)

If you're running it online, it aborts after about a minute. I have a local Sage installation, and it took more than a few minutes but less than 8 hours.

@PeterTaylor Thanks a lot! I am trying Visual Code using Python and Sage environment. As you said, it takes some time but it works! I am now looking for one-free sequences in $A_6$ of length 12 and 4 distinct elements, it is taking long time (maybe there are not). By the way, I've just came up with an interesting question: do you think that proving there is NO one-product free sequence with $k$ distinct elements and length $n$, implies there is also NO one-free sequence of length $n$ and $l$ distinct elements, for any $l>k$? Intuitively, the less distinct elements, more likely is but...

No, that's clearly false. Otherwise considering $k=1$ you would have $D(G)$ equals the largest order of a cyclic subgroup.
